# Renault Modus 1.4 drains battery - whirring noise suddenly begins after 10 days not moving, engine cold, all switched off

Tags: engine, battery, noise, cold

I left my car parked up (Renault Modus 1.4) and did not drive it for 10 days (in 'lockdown'). Then one evening I heard a whirring noise in the engine (after 10 days quiet, totally cold and switched off) and by the next morning the battery was totally flat.

I have recharged the battery and all is going well again, but I am afraid the car will start using some 'hidden' motor or pump again after many days idle (even totally switched off) and flatten the battery again.

This happened about six months ago also. The position of the noise is to the right of the main engine block and level with the top - looks like a pump or motor on a very wide hose - possibly for hot air?

Would be very appreciative if someone can help me trace this fault, please.

Vincent B

Comment: Disconnect battery during long periods on non use.